# How to parse number such as "6.465.654" (without decimal and separated by dot)?

Tags: c#, double

I tried this:

```
[Test]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    var x = "1.852.520";

    var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberGroupSeparator = ".", NumberDecimalDigits = 0 };
    var n = double.Parse(x, nfi);

    n.Should().Be(1852.520);
}
```

But it does not work. I expected the result to be `1852.520`.

Comment: What doesn't work with it ? What should the outcome be ? What is the current outcome you are getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`NumberFormatInfo` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberformatinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Initializes a new writable instance of the NumberFormatInfo class that
>   is culture-independent (**invariant**).

That means it uses [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has also `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx). I think your program confuses which `.` is `NumberDecimalSeparator` or [`NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx) and that's why it throws [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.formatexception.aspx).

For example this works;

```
var x = "1.852,520";

var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberGroupSeparator = ".", 
                                 NumberDecimalDigits = 3,
                                 NumberDecimalSeparator = "," };
var n = double.Parse(x, nfi);
```

Even the last `.` can be decimal separator or group separator. **Compiler can't know that**.

If you define `NumberDecimalSeparator` other than `.` in your `NumberFormatInfo` constructor, problem will be solved.

In such a case, number will be `185252`. I don't understand your `1852.520` example by the way. If `.` is decimal separator in `1852.520`, that won't work as I said. If `.` is group separator, it will be `185252`. This `1.852.520` will be representation of your double value.

Answer (score 0):

That number isn't `1852.520`, it's `1852520`.  The number is parsed  just fine, you're just not validating it correctly.  You have period as a group separator.

You'll also need to set the `NumberDecimalSeparator` to something.  It will default to `"."`, which is what you have as a group separator.  You probably want it to be `","`.

Comment: "The number is parsed just fine", It doesn't. Just tried the OP's code.

Comment: I believe it has to do with `NumberDecimalSeparator`, the code in question would work *(parsing)* for those cultures which has different `NumberDecimalSeparator` than `.`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the same character for both the `NumberGroupSeparator` and `NumberDecimalSeparator` properties of the [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object. While I can't find anything in the MSDN documentation that specifically says so, that does **not** appear to be a valid combination, as shown by the following test code:

```
    private bool SameSeparatorValid(char c)
    {
        string testValue = String.Format("1{0}852{0}520", c);
        double expected = 1852.52;
        var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo
        {
            NumberDecimalSeparator = c.ToString(),
            NumberGroupSeparator = c.ToString()
        };
        try
        {
            double actual = Double.Parse(testValue, nfi);
            return (expected == actual);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void IterateCultures()
    {
        string msgFormat = "Found {0} cultures (of {1})" 
            + " where NumberGroupSeparator == NumberDecimalSeparator";
        var allCis = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
        var cis = allCis.Where(
            ci => ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator 
                == ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
        Console.WriteLine(msgFormat, cis.Count(), allCis.Count());

        var allAscii = Enumerable.Range(0, 127);
        var asciis = allAscii
            .Where(c => SameSeparatorValid((char)c));
        msgFormat = "Found {0} ASII characters (of {1})" 
            + " where NumberGroupSeparator == NumberDecimalSeparator is valid";
        Console.WriteLine(msgFormat, asciis.Count(), allAscii.Count());
   }
```

which, on my machine, produces the following output:

```
Found 0 cultures (of 354) where NumberGroupSeparator == NumberDecimalSeparator
Found 0 ASII characters (of 127) where NumberGroupSeparator == NumberDecimalSeparator is valid
```